# Laravel 4 jquery Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am new to Laravel 4. I have a page within which I have 3 tabs(basically big clickable divs) to load the different user information. What I would like to do is that I would like to be able to click on those tabs,make jquery ajax request,bring back a partial view and update a part of page with that partial view. I would like to able to do that for every tab.

I got the click event firing.I also tried different code to accomplish ajax request. For some reason, nothing happens. I do not know if I am missing something in route.php. Could anyone please give me some code on how to do that? or may be some other idea?

I did this::

Route.php

```
Route::post('userInfo','UserController@showInfo');
```

jqueryAjax:

```
$("divtoUpdatePartialView").click(function(){

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:Not Sure,
  data: { id: userId }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( msg );
});

}
```

I tried using Base Url too, but nothing happens. I have an ajax library declared on my master page. Could you please help me or give me some other ideas?

Thank you very much for your answer. I tried that way, this is what I have...

```
Route.php:

Route::get('user_Profile/userInfo', 'UserController@getshow');
```

The ajax:

```
var  userId='1';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'user_Profile/userInfo',
    data: { id: userId }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "the messageis "+msg );
});


My userController::

public function getshow()
    {
           return "No ajax";
    if (Request::ajax()) {

        return "yeahhhh";
    $html=View::make('user.userProfile')->nest('partial', 'user.userInfoPartial')-        >with('title',$title)->render();


}
}
```

When I directly access the page I receive "No ajax", but when I try the ajax-way,nothing happens.Could you see what I am missing??

Thank you again for your help..

Comment: When you check Network tab in dev tools/firebug, was the ajax request actually sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `url` should be the path/pattern you have used in your `route` and in this case it's

```
userInfo
```

The `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'userInfo',
    data: { id: userId }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( msg );
});
```

Also, make sure that, you can directly access the page from your browser's address bar using

```
http://yourdomain.com/userInfo
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Could you please see my response above and help me on what I am doing wrong? Thanks again

Comment: I got it!!!!!! The problem was that I had to use GET instead of POST since my route is Route::get....Thank you so much..it helped me a lot....

Comment: @user2569653, but in your question you have `Route::post('userInfo','UserController@showInfo);`!

Comment: @Sheikh-I am sorry but I was referring to the second part of my code where I have used 'get'.Anyway, both work as long as the route and ajax posting type match.Thank you. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

return sentence should go AFTER the if sentence;

```
   public function getshow(){

    if (Request::ajax()) {
        $html=View::make('user.userProfile')->nest('partial', 'user.userInfoPartial')-        >with('title',$title)->render();
        return "yeahhhh";
    }
           return "No ajax";
}
```

Return sentence exits the function, that means that any further code is not going to be executed :)