# Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

I'm trying to use Ajax in Laravel to have search results populate the "search_results_div" div without having to leave the page.

Right now I'm getting this error message: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where `` LIKE %%)".

So it looks like `orders` is getting sent but nothing else is. This is my first time with Ajax so while the code is not working I don't understand where I'm going wrong, so any help or pointers would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

***The search_column and search_input are added to the form via JS after search_table has an input. I have hard-coded what this will look like for simplicity's sake and have also tried the code after hard-coding the inputs in and received the same error message. All the same I thought I'd point this out as well.***

Here is my View:

```
 <div class="large-6 columns">
{{Form::open( array('route' => 'search', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'search_form'))}}      

    {{ Form::select('search_table',
    array(
            'select'        => 'Search...',
            'orders'        => 'Search orders',
        ), null, array('id' => 'search_table')) }}

<div class="search_box" id="search_column_div">
    <select id='search_column'>
    <option value='created_at'>by date created</option>     
</select>
</div>

<div id="search_input_div">
    <input id='search_input' class='search_input' placeholder='Enter Order Name'/>
</div>

{{ Form::submit('Search', array('id' => 'search_button','class' => 'button expand radius search_button no_display'))}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>

      <div id="search_results_div">
      </div>
</div>
```

My JS (My guess is here is where the problem is):

```
 /*AJAX Search*/
$('#search_form').click(runSearch);

var runSearch = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $('form#search_form').submit(function(){
            $.ajax(
                {
                url: '/search',
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                search_table: $('#search_table').val(),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("Success!");
                    $('#search_results_div').htlm('Yes');
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                    alert('Somethin went wrong');
                }
            });
        });
};
```

And my Controller:

```
public function searchPost(){
$search_table   = Input::get('search_table');
$search_column  = Input::get('search_column');
$search_input   = Input::get('search_input');

$search = DB::table($search_table)->where($search_column, 'LIKE', "%{$search_input}%")->get();
return $search;
```

}

And my Route:

```
/*Search Page for Ajax*/
    Route::post('/search', array(
        'as'    => 'search',
        'uses'  => 'HomeController@searchPost'
    ));
```

Thanks again for any input or advice!

Comment: Your JS doesn't submit any data.

Comment: Lol I'm still trying to get it to just not crash. But to that point I thought that with the "success" section that I could tell it to pass the returned data (data) into the "search_results_div"'s html. Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form's `select` doesn't have a `search_column` `name` attribute, which is the name that Laravel uses to identify the field when using `Input::get()`.

Use something like this :

```
<select id="whatever" name="search_column">
```

As for the Javascript, try this code :

```
$('#search_form').click(runSearch);

var runSearch = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form#search_form').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            type: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: $('#search_form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Success!");
                $('#search_results_div').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
                alert('Somethin went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

First you don't need to post it in JSON format, the default URL-encoded format is more than enough and works just fine with Laravel's `Input::get("variable")` (I'm not even sure if it actually accepts JSON at all).

Next, the actual data wasn't present in your code, so your request was empty and obviously Laravel wasn't happy because all three input variables were empty and the DB query was failing (by the way, you should use [validation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation) to check if the input is present and if not return a nice & clean error message instead of failing completely).

The `data` variable is set to [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) your form, it "converts" your form into an URL-encoded query string.

Finally the success function sets the HTML content of `search_results_div` to the data returned by Laravel (you should return a view there, currently you just return JSON).

I suggest you also look at some of these questions, they may contain code that you can fix using the answers provided and then reuse :

- [follow and unfollow using single button with jquery & ajax, by laravel controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163499/follow-and-unfollow-using-single-button-with-jquery-ajax-by-laravel-controlle)
- [Laravel 4 jquery Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577555/laravel-4-jquery-ajax-request)
- [How to use Ajax with jQuery in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588139/how-to-use-ajax-with-jquery-in-laravel-4)
- [Laravel 4, jQuery .ajax, No post input received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519285/laravel-4-jquery-ajax-no-post-input-received)
- [Retrieve Values form Jquery Ajax Json in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112453/retrieve-values-form-jquery-ajax-json-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code and am still getting the "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where `` LIKE %%)" error message.

Comment: Also thanks for the explanation, still really new to this ajax stuff so every bit helps.

Comment: *facepalm. Ugh. Lol. Well I corrected that as well but I'm still getting the "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where `` LIKE %%)" message

Comment: One thing is the the fields are added by js as the user fills one. So originally only the search_table field is there but each one is added by js after the previous is filled and it ends up looking like what I have in the post. I have already tried hardcoding everything in and I still get the same error message

Comment: Your `select` only has an `id` attribute, but in URL-encoded form data, fields are identified by their `name` attribute.

Comment: That got it. At least I think so. Now I'm getting tons of stuff back lol. Pages and pages of info and it looks like its all the orders that match the search query, but ALL of the info for ALL of the matches lol. Thanks though!

Comment: If you put that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.